# Getting jQuery tooltip to have a tip start as active when page first loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, imagemap

I'm using the jQuery tooltip plug in on an image map.  When a part of the image is hovered over, the tip appears. This is activated with the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $("map > area").tooltip({ positionLeft: true });
});
```

The html for the image map is set up like this:

```
<map name="Map"> 
  <area shape="rect" coords="36,466,64,507" href="link.aspx" alt="Alt Title" title="ToolTip Title" /> 
  <area shape="rect" coords="36,466,64,507" href="link.aspx" alt="Alt Title2" title="ToolTip Title2" /> 
</map>
```

I'd like to have one of the tool tips be in the active (or hovered) state when the page first loads. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this, or if it is even possible.

Has anybody used this plugin and have any ideas of how I could implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

When the page is finished loading you can trigger the mouseover.

```
$("[name='Map']").trigger("mouseover");
```

Comment: Wouldn't that trigger all of the tool tips?  I would like to be able to set one of the area's to active like:

<area shape="rect" coords="36,466,64,507" href="link.aspx" alt="Alt Title" title="ToolTip Title" class="active" />

So this tool tip will default to thinking it's in the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

You could focus mouse on preferable part of the map or trigger event (probably hover) that activates tooltip.